# Maintianing ActiveRecord associations created using FactoryBot in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot, minitest

I'm attempting to speed up some tests for a Rails controller and a bottleneck has to do with large numbers of objects being created and persisted to the database.  I'm attempting to replace most of those `create` calls with `build` calls to address this.

Running `Rails 5.1`, and using `MiniTest 5.10.3`, with `FactoryBot 5.0.2`.

I'm attempting to go from this

```
@user = create(:user)
@item1 = create(:item)
@item1 = create(:item)

@transaction1 = create(:transaction, buyer: @buyer, item: @item1)
@transaction2 = create(:transaction, buyer: @buyer, item: @item2)
```

In this application `item` represents a sellable object, `user` represents a purchaser and `transaction` is the object that creates the two.  The `User` class also has an association added to it `transaction_checkout_items` which returns all `Transaction` items which are in a state where the purchase can be completed.

So, with each test we're creating a myriad of objects and saving them all to the database.  It's slow but it works.  Still, I want it to be faster, so I've tried replacing the existing setup with something like this:

```
@user = create(:user)
def build_transaction_checkout_items(user, item)
  user.transaction_checkout_items.build(attributes_for(:transaction, 
                                                        buyer: user, 
                                                        sale_price: item.sale_price, 
                                                        item: item))
end

@item1 = build_stubbed(:item)
@item2 = build_stubbed(:item)
@transaction1 = build_transaction_checkout_items(@buyer, @item1)
@transaction2 = build_transaction_checkout_items(@buyer, @item2)
```

This seems to work as long as I'm in the test.  If I drop a binding in my test and check the objects `@user` returns the user object, `@user.transaction_checkout_items` returns a `Transaction::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` object containing all my associated transactions, and the individual transactions have their associated items attached.  However, If I put a `binding.pry` into the controller method which actually does the work, and look at the `User` object I see the correct one, but `user.transaction_checkout_items` now returns an empty `Transaction::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` object with nothing in it.  Essentially the associations vanish, and this makes sense to me as the controller is pulling the `User` object from the database and going to work on it, and this new object is missing the associations.  I've considered trying to stub out an `any_instance` method on the `User` class so that whenever `#transaction_checkout_items` is called it returns the collection of `Transaction` objects but I don't see any way to create a new `::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` object.  I can't simply use an array or other collection for this as there are methods on the `::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` that need to be called for the controller logic to work.

So here I am on a Friday blocked.  Is my idea of stubbing `transaction_checkout_items` on any `User` instance a good one, and if so how do I do it?  Or is there an alternate strategy anyone can suggest that will allow the MiniTest stubbed associations to persist and be available when the controller code runs?

Answer (score 2):

> Is my idea of stubbing transaction_checkout_items on any User instance a good one, and if so how do I do it?

Stubbing out ActiveRecord methods is almost always a bad idea. It will couple your tests heavily to the implementation and potentially will make it difficult to update Rails / ActiveRecord as if anything changes in the framework your tests start breaking. There might be also lots of funny side effects you haven't thought about.

The question is also what do you actually want to test? If you start stubbing out these methods, what are you testing? In a controller / integration test, I would expect you want to test to fetch the correct records from the database.

Using build vs. create to improve test performance is a good trick but, as you already discovered, is only valuable if you use the same objects in the test. This is unfortunately not possible for integration tests and you need / should persists the records.

> Or is there an alternate strategy anyone can suggest that will allow the MiniTest stubbed associations to persist and be available when the controller code runs?

I would think about why this is slow and if this is actually really a problem. How long does your test & whole test suite run or is this just a premature optimisation?

If the reason it's slow is solely because you need to create a lot of test data you could use fixtures or seed your database instead. This would both be faster than using FactoryBot although brings different issues (e.g. [MysteryGuest](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/mystery-guest))

Comment: The tests for this particular controller are very slow, and I'm hoping to optimize them as our overall test suite takes a long time to run. Stubbing AR methods isn't something I want to do, but a possible solution I've arrived at after trying many thing that didn't work. Something like seeding the database is a non-starter, as we have thousands of tests using these same model classes and a seeded DB would doubtless break a lot of them. I do want to test that the controller is asking the DB for the right records, but without it actually taking the time to query the DB.

Comment: `I do want to test that the controller is asking the DB for the right records, but without it actually taking the time to query the DB.` <- This is pretty much a contradiction. Either you want to test the db or you don't.

Comment: If this test is too slow, the best option you have is to split it into smaller and faster tests. This also has the advantage that you can parallelize it.